# Check if X minutes have passed from a specific time

Tags: php

I'm having a problem while trying to compare two times, the thing I want to do is something like this:

```
$time = date("H:i:sa");
```

//my time on my table looks like this `00:20:00` that's the echo of `$row['time']`

```
if (strtotime($row['time'])+300 >= strtotime($time )) 
{
   echo "You are out";
   exit();
}
else
{
   echo "You are in";
   exit();
}
```

I want to check if TimeArrive + 5 minutes is bigger than the current time, but I have no clue on what I'm doing wrong, the code seems to do to something but I think it's not working at least if I try to echo I'm not getting the correct time for example if I `echo strtotime($TimeArrive)+300;` it just outputs `300`.

I already checked some topics around here, but most of them don't work on my code, or just outputs the same 300 that I'm getting...

---

Small test:

```
if (strtotime($row['TimeIn'],strtotime("+5 minutes")) <= strtotime($t)) {
```

Still got no luck trying this way

Comment: Unless you are posting the times to a database or using sessions and are constantly checking with each page load, you will need to use javascript to do this.

Comment: @Mech one of the values the $TimeArrive I get it from the database and the values on the database are stored like this 00:20:00

Comment: Updated the question with my sql output

Comment: Double check your timezones in both PHP and the Database.  They should be the same and it will make things easier in the long run if they are both UTC.

Comment: @AlexBarker they are the same I'm also forcing them to be the same on the php page

Comment: `if (strtotime("00:20:00") + 300 <= time()) {` works as expected for me, double check your inputs are what you think they are.

Comment: @AlexBarker oh just noticed that when I have this `echo strtotime($row['TimeIn']);` my output is `1600298400` but when I remove the  `strtotime` and leave it just like this `echo $row['TimeIn'];` I get the correct output of` 00:20:00`

Comment: My issue is probably there, just don't know why I'm getting those numbers

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found out the problem!

I had to convert it back using `date()` that's why I was getting all those numbers...

The final code would look something like this:

```
$timechecker = date("H:i:sa",strtotime($row['TimeIn'])+60);
                        if ($timechecker <= $t) {
```

Thanks, everyone in the comments trying to help me out it made me look to some stuff that I was not looking like confirming what my output was :D